# do an event only on element clicked same class

Tags: jquery

i wonder if it is possible to do an event only on the element clicked,
although this element have the same class,
and if inside or next to this element there is a div with the class 'subcategory', show it using toggleClass method.
here the html.

```
<ul>
    <li class="catname">something</li>
    <li class="catname">
       something
      <div class="subcategory none">some hidden content to show</div>
    </li>
    <li class="catname">something</li>
</ul>
```

This is what I tried:

```
$(document).on("click",".catname", function (event) { 
    $(".subcategory").next().toggleClass('none') 
});
```

Also this:

```
$(".catname").bind("click", function() {
    $(".subcategory").next().toggleClass('none')
});
```

Thank you

Comment: show us the jquery code that you have tried yet so far.

Comment: use event binding on `class`

Comment: here:     $(document).on("click",".catname", function (event) {
    $(".subcategory").next().toggleClass('none')
  });

Comment: @NonsonoStatoio You should edit and post that code into your question.

Comment: put this code in your question. not as comment

Comment: use `$(this)` inside event to find from current `class` clicked.

Comment: @ Parth Trivedi the bind method is okay solution, but i want to toggleclass 'none' only on the item selected, in this case if there is multiple divs with 'subcategory' div inside it, they are all shown.

  $( ".catname" ).bind( "click", function() {
    $(".subcategory").next().toggleClass('none')
  });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `this` keyword within the click handler to reference the element which raised the event. From there you can traverse the DOM to `find()` the inner element. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.catname', function (event) { 
    $(this).find('.subcategory').toggleClass('none');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/maf4ak0f/)